# How to group exact timestamp information into time period bins and average?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a timestamped dataframe with two columns, containing sales of different products. What I want to do is create a plot of a certain products sale numbers in 10 minutes with 5 minute shifts, going back to 10 days back. I want the intervals shift like shown in the image. I have tried to use between function in a datetime shifting loop but it takes forever to fill up a list , shown in the code section, any faster solution?

[image]

```
example_apple = []
while interval_time <=  end_time:
example_apple.append(df_thisyear.filter(df_thisyear.TIMESTAMP.between(start_time, interval_time)) \
                               .filter(df_thisyear.product == 'Apple').count())
start_time = start_time + timedelta(minutes=5)
interval_time = interval_time + timedelta(minutes=5)
```

Comment: Are yo able to provide text dataframes of the input and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Key for you is to sample the "exact time stamps" down to a column with desired "time bins" (e.g., 5-minute intervals). Once you do that, all yours rows may have different exact timestamps, but those that belong to the same time interval (bin) will have the same `bin` column value. Then, you you can easily select them.

If your timestamps are distributed over a span from 1-20, say like this:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': range(1, 21)})
```

and your have a list of start times for your desired time interval bins, such as this:

```
bins = [1, 6, 11, 16]
```

then you can sample the "exact" timestamps down into "time period bins" like this:

```
data['time_bin'] = pd.cut(
    data['timestamp'], 
    bins,
    labels=list(range(1, len(bins))),
    right=False
)
```

This will give you 1 single additional column `time_bin`, which is the down-sampled "exact timestamps" from the `timestamp` column into the `time_bin`s that you have defined in your list.

A great, long explanation of different time-manipulation techniques see [here](https://davidbpython.com/advanced_python/slides/handout-83-3.html)

With that binned df, you can use `df.groupby()` to group over each of the time intervals that you have in your new column. For example, let's count how many `timestamp`s we now have in each of our `time_bin`s:

```
data.groupby('time_bin').count()[['timestamp']]

          timestamp
time_bin           
1                 5
2                 5
3                 5
```

With that group, do whatever: Count the number of apples and oranges, analyze each time bin separately, average over 2 time bins, take a cumulative sum or rolling average over n groups, etc.

Comment: I couldn't understand the first part, should create a column for matching intervals, wouldn't it require N extra columns for each 10 mins? if so, that wouldn't work for a large dataset my dataset contains millions of rows.

Comment: No. Downsampling adds 1 single column, which - for each row - contains the information to which time bin it belongs, see updated answer with specific code example

Comment: I think I understand but what about overlapping data, I want the last 10 mins, then after 5 mins later I wan the last 10 mins so there will be 5 minutes of overlapping data. How can I get those.

Comment: There is no *overlapping data*. Each timestamp belongs to exactly 1 time bin... What you want is an analysis that spans 2 time bins... Take the steps above, then apply `pd.rolling` to `data.groupby('time_bin').count()[['timestamp']]`

Comment: there is overlapping data, I found a solution to my problem : df_thisyear.groupBy(F.window("TIMESTAMP", "10 minutes", "5 minutes")), groups values by 10 minute intervals and 5 minute shifts.